# Best way to store XML data into database

Tags: java, mysql, xml

I have XML file with multiple level of children. Which is best way to store that data into database? To make different table for node and save data with relationship or? What to do if we have 50 different nodes ?

**Similar XML**

```
<storage>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <storage_item gender="Men's">
         <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
         <price>39.95</price>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color>
            <color image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color>
            <color image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color>
         </size>
      </storage_item>
      <storage_item gender="Women's">
         <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
         <price>42.50</price>
         <size description="Small">
            <color image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color>
            <color image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color>
            <color image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color>
         </size>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color>
            <color image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color>
            <color image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color>
            <color image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color>
            <color image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color>
         </size>
         <size description="Extra Large">
            <color image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color>
            <color image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color>
         </size>
      </storage_item>
   </product>
</storage>
```

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it. If you just want to store it and get it back as-is, use a blob. If you want to actually work with  the data, e.g., find the average price of your items, break it up and create different tables as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this XML to JSON format and save it in a NoSQL database like MongoDB.

UPDATE : If you need to save it into a SQL Database I think you would need to use JAXB or XMLBeans to convert to java objects and then use JDBC or JPA to save it into the DB.

Bonus idea (Tristan) : In second solution, you may also chose for which portion of XML you actually need precise data in SQL DB and for the other portion you would store it in a CLOB field.

Comment: i know that, but I use relation db (mySQL)

Comment: Sorry, I just added the second sentence after his comment.

Comment: I already convert it to java. But is that best way to manipulate with xml ? look what i i have 50 nested nodes I cant make 50 tables....

Comment: I think it depends if you don't need consistency in this data, you could save the `xml` directly in a column. You could create `products` and `storage_items` tables and save `size` in a column in xml format.